# Fastest way to find a word in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| name | sentence |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | The cat is on the table. |
| Bob | One might say that caterpillars are majestic |

I want to get as a result a dataframe like this:

| name | sentence | contains_cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | The cat is on the table. | True |
| Bob | One might say that caterpillars are majestic | False |

So the column "contains_cat" has to show True only if the corresponding row of column "sentence" contains exactly the word cat (not **cat**erpillar, for example).

I wrote a code that does this, searching for words like " cat " or " cat." .
Is it possible to speed this up, considering that I'd like to do this for large dataframes and for many words?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Tom', 'Bob'],
              'sentence': ['The cat is on the table.', 'One might say that caterpillars are majestic']})
df['contains_cat'] = False

string_to_find = [' cat ',
                  'Cat ',
                  ' cat.']
for ii in range(0,len(string_to_find)):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'dummy': [string_to_find[ii]] * len(df)})
    df['contains_cat'] = df['contains_cat'] | \
                         [x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(df1['dummy'], df['sentence'])]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.contains`:

```py
df["contains_cat"] = df["sentence"].str.contains(r'\bcat\b')
```

Note that the regex pattern `\bcat\b` will find exact matches for the word `cat` (but not `cat` as part of a substring of a larger words such as `caterpillar`).  Regex search is enabled by default with `str.contains`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if the sentence is "My pet (cat) is black" or "No pets cat/dog allowed"?

Comment: @user13748410 You could try using `(?<!\w)cat(?!\w)`, [see the demo](https://regex101.com/r/vaq84j/1).